# How to make a C++ program run maximized automatically?

Tags: visual-c++, window, maximize, maximize-window

I need to know whether there is a code for a C++ program to automatically maximize the program  window since I always have to maximize the window when I run the program.
I'm using Windows 7.

I am very much new to C++.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to initialize window? Are you using library or using WinAPI directly?

Comment: @Dishon, Well my answer was working, why unaccept?

Comment: @Tejendra, done. Better late than never, right? :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this It will Work

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include "Windows.h"
#include "tchar.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 //Write Your Code HERE//
  HWND hWnd;
  SetConsoleTitle(_T("test"));
  hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, _T("test"));
  HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  COORD NewSBSize = GetLargestConsoleWindowSize(hOut);
  SMALL_RECT DisplayArea = {0, 0, 0, 0};

  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hOut, NewSBSize);

  DisplayArea.Right = NewSBSize.X - 1;
  DisplayArea.Bottom = NewSBSize.Y - 1;

  SetConsoleWindowInfo(hOut, TRUE, &DisplayArea);

  ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
 _getch();
  return 0;
}
```

It Will show your Output in Maximized Window.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZED)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You would have to run a program you created, [FindWindow(your target)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then invoke ShowWindow(SW_MAXIMIZED) on it. Note that this is achievable through [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and no C++.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna maximize your program when it runs you can use this code in your Main Form

```
    __fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent* Owner) : TForm(Owner)
{

           WindowState = wsMaximized;
}
```

Or if you want to maximize your program during codes e.g. pressing a button then you can use this code if it's in you're Main form:

```
ShowWindow(this->Handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Or this one if you're in a child one :

```
ShowWindow(Application->Handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
#include <windows.h>

void maximizeWindow(){
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
}
```